# angularjs , a is undefined in foreach, looping through elements with class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im attempting to loop through a list of elements with a certain class in angular but I think Im going about it the wrong way.

Im now getting the error `a is undefined`

```
<div class="add-filter-tags" data-filter="{{filter.filter_type}}" ng-class="{'tag_selected' : tag_selected }" ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-click="tag_selected = !tag_selected;">{{filter.filter_type}}</div>
```

So I click a few of them to add the `tag_selected` class...

I have this code in a function that gets called later on...

```
angular.forEach(document.querySelector('.tag_selected')), function(value, key){
        window.alert('test');
}
```

And thats whats giving me the error.

I guess this is more of a general question, how do I loop through elements with classes in angularjs? The documentation for the ForEach is fairly small and only refers to pre declared arrays.

Comment: You've closed off your forEach instead of passing the anonymous function in as a parameter: `angular.forEach(document.querySelector('.tag_selected')) <-- extra parenthesis` Is that your actual code?

Comment: oh oops! I feel like an idiot!!, thanks, I changed that and it fixed it, the only problem is it is only alerting one 'test' even if I have several `tag_selected` classes

Comment: You need `querySelectorAll` for multiple objects. `querySelector` only pulls the first

Comment: Thank you! Feel free to give as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
angular.forEach(document.querySelectorAll('.tag_selected'), function(value, key) {
    window.alert('test');
});
```

Comment: The angular forEach loop, there is two arguments one is for the list of items and the another argument is the callback function to be invoked for each item, previously the angular for loop is closed in the first argument itself.